# IE Background image with transparency

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Why would this simple line of code work perfectly in firefox e.t.c but in IE it creates some weird fade issue.

```
#content { background:url(images/bg-trans.png) repeat; padding:25px 21px; width:918px; overflow:hidden; }
```

Its like the transparency is started in a corner but then it gradually fades out...very annoying!!!

Comment: Screen capture or a link to the problem would be nice, as it's quite hard to see now what bg-trans.png looks like. And what version of IE?

Comment: Thanks, its a pain in the ass...

Comment: perhaps this is the same issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662616/background-colour-of-a-png-in-ie8
??

Comment: works fine for both Firefox and IE7 & 8 for me. IE6 have a terrible look.

Comment: I dont support IE6 :@)  Happy days for those still using it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this awhile ago with IE8.

It's because you have a 1x1 background png with transparency.  For some reason, IE8 borks on these, and applies them as a fading gradient down a large area.

The solution, oddly enough, is to simply make your background .png file bigger in dimension.  1x2 or 2x1 will do it.  To be nice to the browsers, something a little bigger is better, 10x10 or 20x20 maybe, as this means they don't have to render it so many times across the background.