# Problem with google maps on IE + pop up layer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, google-maps, modal-dialog, overlay

I'm using a jQuery plug-in "Boxy" (http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/) to open a pop-up layer and show a map on it. It works perfectly on all browsers except IE (7 & 8). Some elements like shadow of the marker & infoWindow are transparent, so that you can see 
background of the page.

Here's the test page: http://kostik.de/maps/create.html (click "edit" to open pop up, then watch Marker and InfoWindow-shadow).

any idea anyone?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border around the infoWindow is an issue with Boxy, it doesn't work on IE8 from their demos either.  Maybe you can try a different lightbox plugin - [Facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox) looks like one that is similar to the style you're after and it works in IE.  You might want to look at [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662616/background-colour-of-a-png-in-ie8) for info about the transparent PNGs in IE.

Comment: OK, another good lib I'm using now is SimpleModal (http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) - it has no issues with IE+Maps