# IE is changing my image's background color...huh?

Tags: html, css, web

I have a really strange problem that I can't explain and fix, it is driving me crazy.

I have this logo that I am showing on a webpage : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnV9i.png
Note the background color value is #400000 or rgb(64,0,0)

I am displaying this image on a webpage set with background color #400000 too.

When displaying it in Firefox, everything's perfect and I can't notice the shift from the background color and the image.

In IE(8) however, the **image's** background color is mysteriously changed to #360000 or rgb(54,0,0)
so the shift from the page's background color to the image is visible...that should not happen.

Why is IE changing my image's background color?? That makes no sense, lol.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I vaguely remember reading that if you use pngcrush on the png it will remove the offending meta data that causes this. Smush it probably does the same thing.

Comment: @David - can you check that link? Currently it goes to http://firequery.binaryage.com/.

Comment: Oh...darn. @slugster, thanks for the heads up =) here's the link I meant to give: [@bobince's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662616/background-colour-of-a-png-in-ie8). (Original comment deleted).

Comment: @David: thanks for the heads up on bobince's article, this is indeed the same identical question.

Comment: I don't think that link went where you expected, but thanks! That is a nifty tool!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>IE8 should not change the color of your image, that is bizarre.</strike>

But it does!
Lets add this to the long list of IE bizarro interpretations.

have you tried using a png with a transparent background instead?

if that's impossible for you, there's an article here describing the IE PNG problem and how to fix it: http://www.biorust.com/tutorials/detail/231/en/
[image]

Comment: Well, that totally did the trick...very weiiird quirck, thank you sir!

Comment: Some editors will put this gamma colour in, one of the more notable programs that I think to does this is Paint.Net. IIRC, Adobe Suite products don't put this colour in the PNG, using the Save for Web options. (I don't think i've seen a definitive list of programs anywhere)